# Extract content of a block from a twig template

Tags: php, twig

Is there any way to extract the source content of a twig template in an acceptable way? Of course I can use a regex pattern, but I think this is not the best solution.

If I have this:

```
{% block test %}
This is a test!
{% endblock %}
```

I want to extract this by using the name of the block:

```
This is a test!
```

Comment: I don't think that any parser understand twig patterns. So regex seems to be the best way

Answer (score 0):

Suppose file we have file: `file.html.twig` with

```
{% block test %}
This is a test!
{% endblock %}
```

to extract `This is a test!` execute a command:

```
sed '/{%/ d' file.html.twig
```

Comment: What if OP has something like: `{% block content %}{% include "child.twig.html" %}{% endif %}`?

Comment: What should be extracted in your opinion?